# Invalid Time.now on RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How do I set the correct Time on RSpec.

```
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Device::Creation::Security>)> Time.now
=> Fri, 01 Jan 2016 10:00:00 CET +01:00
```

On rails console I have the correct time:

```
[1] pry(main)> Time.now
=> 2015-12-11 12:41:36 -0500
```

I don't want to stub it, because I'm not passing the time to my class. Have the following method in the class I'm testing:

```
  def within_expiration?
    Time.now - user.sms_sent_date < time_limit_in_seconds
  end
```

This is not behaving as expected because `Time.now` is Jan 1, 2016

`user.sms_sent_date` has right date.

Comment: Sure you haven't stub `Time.now` already or use a gem like [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop)?

Comment: I didn't stub `Time.now` and not using in my spec or on my spec_helper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any library that is currently altering your `Time` in the spec.

For example, one of the most commonly used is [`Timecop`](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop). Make sure you don't setup it globally, instead use the blocks or `before/after` to properly mock the date and teardown the mock when no longer required.

Comment: I'll don't have it setup globaly and I don't have it on the current spec

Comment: @neo is Timecop used for another spec in the test suite? It's hard to conceive of any other reason that `Time.now` would return a different value. Have you tried running the failing spec by itself?

Comment: You're right, looks like it was configured for test environment. I'm gonna try to stub it to get a time closer to current time.